# meaning of leading slash("/") in spring-mvc return statement

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, path, maven-jetty-plugin

When I use spring mvc I write controller methods like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createCompanyAddPayment(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        return "/another/jsp";
    }
```

I noticed that it doesn't work when I use `jetty:run` of maven plugin

```
problem accessing /WEB-INF/pages//another/jsp.jsp. Reason:

    /WEB-INF/pages//another/jsp.jsp
```

When I use tomcat - it works good.

I understand that problem with double slash("//") delimeter.

Can you explain
1. What does leading slash means in spring controller return statement?
2. Why does on tomcat it work but doesn't work on jetty maven plugin ?
3. Is it safety to rewrite return statement like this?:

```
return "another/jsp";
```

P.S.

viewResolver:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this type of mapping the return value represents a view name, and to reason properly about the delimeters you have to consider the configuration of your ViewResolverInstance, the view URL is being assembled as

```
view.setUrl(getPrefix() + viewName + getSuffix());
```

so if you have e.g.

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

your returned view names have to be without the `"/"` if you were to configure the prefix as `<beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views" />` you would have to use a leading slash. So its safe to rewrite your return statements, moreover, your case shows the importance of it.

Regarding your second question. Would welcome other people to assert it, but, as far as I know there is a difference in the way that File URL handlers are implemented in Jetty and Tomcat. If you have a URI for a web resource, having a single or a double slash is a significant difference, and both Jetty and Tomcat are aligned with the  RFC 2396 specification. However, when it comes to URI designating a file, Jetty seems stricter (better in my view), while Tomcat considers double slashes valid.

Check the debate under this Jetty issue https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-386, maybe it will make more sense than

Comment: posted view resolover in question.

Comment: You don't answer: **2. Why does on tomcat it work but doesn't work on jetty maven plugin ?**